# Confused with network byte order and host byte order

Tags: c

I'm getting terribly confused with **host byte order** and **network byte order**. I know network byte order is big endian. And I know host byte order in my case is little endian.

So, if I'm printing data I would need to convert to host byte order in order to get the correct value right?

My problem is I am trying to print the value of data returned by `htonl`. Here is my example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int bits = 12;
    char *ip = "132.89.39.0";
    struct in_addr addr;
    uint32_t network, netmask, last_addr;
    uint32_t total_hosts;

    inet_aton(ip, &addr);
    printf("Starting IP:\t%s\n", inet_ntoa(addr.s_addr));

    netmask = (0xFFFFFFFFUL << (32 - bits)) & 0xFFFFFFFFUL;
    netmask = htonl(netmask);
    printf("Netmask:\t%s\n", inet_ntoa(netmask));

    network = addr.s_addr & netmask;
    printf("Network:\t%s\n", inet_ntoa(network));

    printf("Total Hosts:\t%d\n", ntohl(netmask));

    return 0;
```

}

`printf("Total Hosts:\t%d\n", ntohl(netmask));` prints the correct value but it prints with a minus sign.If I use `%u`I get the wrong value.

Where am I going wrong?

With %d output is:

```
Starting IP:    132.89.39.0
Netmask:        255.240.0.0
Network:        132.80.0.0
Total Hosts:    -1048576
```

With %u output is:

```
Starting IP:    132.89.39.0
Netmask:        255.240.0.0
Network:        132.80.0.0
Total Hosts:    4293918720
```

I've been stuck on this for 2 days. Something seemingly so simple has threw me off completely. I don't want anyone to solve the problem, but a push in the right direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

If you see, the prototype of `htonl()` is

> `uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);`

so, it returns an `uint32_t`, which is of unsigned type. Printing that value using `%d` , (which expects an argument of type `signed int`) is improper.

At least, you need to use `%u` for getting the `unsigned` value. Generally, if possible, try to use `PRIu32` MACRO for printing fixed-width (32) unsigned integers.

Comment: If I print with `%u` I get a completely different value. I have edited my code because the line causing the problem was meant to be `printf("Total Hosts:\t%u\n", ntohl(netmask));`

Comment: @Torra isn't it like `inet_ntoa()` takes one `struct in_addr`?

Comment: @Torra Also, __please do not change the question after getting an answer__. You can always edit your question to __append__ more information or correct any mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

There are currently a variety of systems that can change between little-endian and bigendian
byte ordering, sometimes at system reset, sometimes at run-time.
We must deal with these byte ordering differences as network programmers because
networking protocols must specify a network byte order. For example, in a TCP segment, there
is a 16-bit port number and a 32-bit IPv4 address. The sending protocol stack and the
receiving protocol stack must agree on the order in which the bytes of these multibyte fields
will be transmitted. The Internet protocols use big-endian byte ordering for these multibyte
integers.
In theory, an implementation could store the fields in a socket address structure in host byte
order and then convert to and from the network byte order when moving the fields to and from
the protocol headers, saving us from having to worry about this detail. But, both history and
the POSIX specification say that certain fields in the socket address structures must be
maintained in network byte order. Our concern is therefore converting between host byte order
and network byte order. We use the following four functions to convert between these two byte
orders.

```
 #include <netinet/in.h>
    uint16_t htons(uint16_t host16bitvalue) ;
    uint32_t htonl(uint32_t host32bitvalue) ;
```

Both return: value in network byte order

```
   uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t net16bitvalue) ;
    uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t net32bitvalue) ;
```

Both return: value in host byte order

In the names of these functions, h stands for host, n stands for network, s stands for short,
and l stands for long. The terms "short" and "long" are historical artifacts from the Digital VAX
implementation of 4.2BSD. We should instead think of s as a 16-bit value (such as a TCP or
UDP port number) and l as a 32-bit value (such as an IPv4 address). Indeed, on the 64-bit
Digital Alpha, a long integer occupies 64 bits, yet the htonl and ntohl functions operate on
32-bit values.
When using these functions, we do not care about the actual values (big-endian or littleendian)
for the host byte order and the network byte order. What we must do is call the
appropriate function to convert a given value between the host and network byte order. On
those systems that have the same byte ordering as the Internet protocols (big-endian), these
four functions are usually defined as null macros.
We will talk more about the byte ordering problem, with respect to the data contained in a
network packet as opposed to the fields in the protocol headers,
We have not yet defined the term "byte." We use the term to mean an 8-bit quantity since
almost all current computer systems use 8-bit bytes. Most Internet standards use the term
octet instead of byte to mean an 8-bit quantity. This started in the early days of TCP/IP
because much of the early work was done on systems such as the DEC-10, which did not use
8-bit bytes.
Another important convention in Internet standards is bit ordering. In many Internet
standards, you will see "pictures" of packets that look similar to the following (this is the first
32 bits of the IPv4 header from RFC 791):

```
0                   1                   2                   3
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|Version|  IHL|   TYPE OF SERCVICE |      TOTAL LENGTH          |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

This represents four bytes in the order in which they appear on the wire; the leftmost bit is the
most significant. However, the numbering starts with zero assigned to the most significant bit.
This is a notation that you should become familiar with to make it easier to read protocol
definitions in RFCs.
A common network programming error in the 1980s was to develop code on Sun
workstations (big-endian Motorola 68000s) and forget to call any of these four functions.
The code worked fine on these workstations, but would not work when ported to littleendian
machines (such as VAXes).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not your conversion between network and host order. That part of your code works perfectly.

The problem is your belief that the netmask, interpreted as an integer, is the number of hosts which match that mask. That is exactly the inverse of the truth.

Consider your 12-bit netmask, 255.240.0.0. Or, in binary:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

As your code indicates, for a host address to match a network address with this netmask, the two addresses need to be identical where the netmask has a `1` bit. Bit positions corresponding to a `0` in the netmask can be freely chosen. The number of such addresses can be determined by considering only the `0` bits. But of course we can't leave those bits as 0s; to count the number of qualifying addresses, we need to prepend a `1`. So the count, in this case, is (exactly as you suspect) 1,048,576:

```
                      1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

One way to compute this value would be to invert the netmask and add 1:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
---------------------------------------------------------------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 (bitwise invert)
                                                              1 (+ 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------
                      1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In 2's-complement arithmetic, this is precisely the same as arithmetic negation. So it is not suprising that when you print the netmask out as a signed integer, you'll see the negative of the expected count. (Printing an unsigned `uint32_t` as a signed `int` is technically undefined behaviour but will probably work as expected on 2's-complement machines with 32-bit ints.)

In short, what you should do to compute the number of qualifying addresses from the netmask is:

```
uint32_t address_count = ~ntohl(netmask) + 1;
```

(which most compilers will optimize to a unary negation opcode, if available.)

Comment: I tried inverting and was always getting 1048575 and couldn't understand why it was always 1 less than the expected value. I assumed that maybe it was using big endian and was losing a bit to the signed bit. This makes sense to me now. Thank you. I was completely off lol.

Comment: @Torra: network order doesn't change the way 2's-complement works :) But it is not a coincidence that ntohl and htonl use unsigned integer types.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the key part of the question: That the actual main problem was the misunderstanding of what value `netmask` contains - top bits set, lower bits cleared. The problems with the singed vs. unsigned interpretation *are* real problems, but more superficial and incidental (correcting the `%d` to a `%u` doesn't get someone with a similar question any closer to understanding why it's showing an unexpected value; correcting the understanding of what value is inside the `netmask` variable does).

Comment: @Torra Since this seems to be the answer that you said was the most helpful to you, do you mind finally giving it the accepted answer checkmark and upvote it? If I was trying to figure out a similar problem this is the answer that would help me the most, and the current other answers would just confuse me.

Comment: P.S. I think C semantics actually guarantee that you can do `-ntohl(netmask)` instead of `~ntohl(netmask) + 1` to get the right result. (The result of unary negation is defined as having the *value* of the negation of the *value* of the operand, and the result of shoving a negative *value* into an unsigned type is defined to basically be the value modulo the maximum that can fit into the type, so in other words, C operations on unsigned integer types are strictly defined so that negation will *portably* do the right thing to the bits.)